calculate and print N! with RISC-V
given some number N in one of my registers i want to print it and print the value of N!
Hi,
given some number N in one of my registers i want to print it and print the value of N!
my problem is that i dont know how to print them in different lines. i tried to usw \n and it didnt work .
like here - instead of printing 6 and in a new line print 720 i get 6720
.data

newline: .asciiz "\n output:"  

.text
main:
    addi t2, zero, 6  # Initialize t2 with the value of N (6 in this case)
    addi t0, zero, 1  
    addi t1, zero, 1  

    # Print N
    add a0, t2, zero
    li a7, 1
    ecall

    # Calculate N!
    ble t2, t1, done
    mul t1, t2, t0

duplicate:
    addi t2, t2, -1
    mul t1, t1, t2
    bgt t2, t0, duplicate  # while N>1

done:
    # Print newline
    la a0, newline  # Load address of newline string
    li a7, 1
    ecall  # Print newline

    # Print N!
    add a0, t1, zero
    li a7, 1
    ecall


    # Exit program
    li a7, 10
    ecall


What environment are you using?

You're using the wrong ecall to print the string.  Also the data directive is .asciz not .asciiz for RARS — don't ignore error and warning messages.
